# CPC 0.00 and two clicks for just 0.1 $

Tags: google-adsense

In my Google Adsense account I noticed that the CPC is 0.00 $?!!! The following screen shot  shows detailed description of the situation:
[image]

Do there any penalties from Google on my account? Why the cost per click is zero?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This just means that those clicks were both deemed invalid by Google... it could be that you clicked on your own ad at some point.

Answer (score 1):

I've also noticed that today's statistics are not always accurate, especially early in the day.  By the end of the day the stats should be better.

Google says that everything for the current month is just "estimated", and sometimes they really mean it.  You'll know you have problems when your finalized earnings go to zero.

Comment: Yep, it even has a disclaimer about this ;) it can read $0.00 if the calucations are not yet calculated and is normally weeks behind.